# What does `pdk-cw-fs` mean in the `groups` definition?

Tags: android, repo

What does `pdk-cw-fs` mean in the `groups` definition?

I notice it in manifest entries like the one below:

```
  <project path="cts" name="platform/cts" groups="cts,pdk-cw-fs,pdk-fs" remote="aosp" />
```

Found here:

https://github.com/LineageOS/android/blob/lineage-16.0/default.xml#L42

Answer (score -1):

According to the post from David Pursehouse here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/1GdH35ColgU

"So you can initialise a workspace with only the projects that belong to a specific group or set of groups.  See the --groups option on the repo init command."

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/stable/subcmds/init.py#148

This is the description in the repo source definition:

```
g.add_option('-g', '--groups',
                 dest='groups', default='default',
                 help='restrict manifest projects to ones with specified '
                      'group(s) [default|all|G1,G2,G3|G4,-G5,-G6]',
                 metavar='GROUP')
```